# datatype date and time for oracle database

Tags: oracle, date, time, types

Which type of data type are used to insert date and time in this format
(`10-Oct-2013, 04:00 PM`) for oracle database..

```
CREATE TABLE OPERATOR (
     LASTPSWDCHANGE DATE, 
     LASTSIGNONDTTM DATE, 
     LASTUPDDTTM DATE 
);
```

Comment: You should always try to provide a code snippet and the exact error message you get (if any). If you don't, it's really hard to guess what your problem really is.

Answer (score 2):

`DATE` is the correct type to store date/time values.The `DATE` data type does not in itself specify any particular format when converting to or from a string.

To convert from string (usually `VARCHAR2`) to `DATE` use

`TO_DATE(<string with date>, <date format>)`

To convert from `DATE` to `VARCHAR2` use

`TO_CHAR(<date>, <date format>`)

There is a default date format which is determined by the locale of the **client**. In tools like Toad or SQL developer the default format often doesn't include the time part.

`DATE` has second precision. For higher precision (millisecond, nanosecond etc) use `TIMESTAMP`.

**EDIT:**

You can find documentation on the [format specifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm) on Oracles website.

In your case, use:

```
TO_DATE('10-Oct-2013, 04:00 PM', 'DD-MON-YYYY, HH:MI PM')
```

Comment: 10-Oct-2013, 04:00 PM this format not insert in my table when i am using DATE datatype why...?

Comment: so which datatype i am use for inserting date and time

Comment: Use the following format specifier: `'DD-MON-YYYY, HH:MI PM'`.

Comment: what is TO_DATE it's datatype

Comment: It is a function that converts a string to a `DATE`.

Comment: how many types datatype use for date and time in oracle table

Comment: i have using  oci_bind_by_name($s, ':LASTPSWDCHANGE', $lpwd); for inserting Data in to database
so whrer i am use this code TO_DATE('10-Oct-2013, 04:00 PM', 'DD-MON-YYYY, HH:MI PM')

Comment: I'd say three or four. `DATE` for date/time. `TIMESTAMP` for high precision date/time and 2 different INTERVAL data types. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#i54330

Comment: In that case you should use a date variable in your programming language. If you are programming in java you should use java.sql.Date.

Answer (score 0):

TIMESTAMP data type  can be used here

```
a TIMESTAMP := TIMESTAMP '2013-10-10 16:00:00';
b TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE := TIMESTAMP '2013-10-10 16:00:00.00 +02:00';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but i have use only this format   10-Oct-2013, 04:00 PM

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATE as datatype. But you can retrieve date in various format using TO_CHAR function.

An example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( LASTPSWDCHANGE ,'DD-Mon-YYYY, HH:MI AM' ), 
       TO_CHAR( LASTSIGNONDTTM ,'DD-Mon-YYYY, HH:MI AM' ), 
       TO_CHAR( LASTUPDDTTM ,   'DD-Mon-YYYY, HH:MI AM' )
FROM OPERATOR
```